# What is the differences between Office 365 APIs and EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365api

What are the differences between Office 365 APIs and EWS (Exchange Web Services) ?

When do I use one or another?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Office365 API only works for Office365, while EWS works for any Exchange server from Exchange2007 up (including Office365). Other than that:

- EWS is SOAP, Office365 API REST
- EWS has a very nice/easy to use managed wrapper for .NET/Java
- EWS has way more features - similar to using an Exchange client for Office365 compared to the webinterface. Things like Tasks are not in the Office365 API afaik.

Comment: And EWS allows you to impersonate another user which is not possible with the Offfice REST API.